# Python wmi module attribute error

Tags: python, wmi

I have downloaded python 3.6.3 & installed wmi extension, wmi module. I'm getting error like "AttributeError: module wmi has no attribute WMI". Please help.

Comment: How you have imported module wmi?

Comment: `from wmi import WMI` than `WMI(..............)` or `import wmi; wmi.WMI(...............)`

Comment: import wmi; c=wmi.WMI();

Answer (score 2):

if your file name is wmi.py:
  rename it

Answer (score 0):

for those that still have the problem install:

1. install wmi

   pip install wmi
2. change code, the code in most tutorial is wrong for some reason, here is the code that worked for me:

> ```
> #import pywmi
> import wmi
>
> def detect_usb():
>     """Detects USB devices connected to the computer.
>
>     Returns:
>         A list of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains information about a USB device.
>     """
>
>     winmsgint = wmi.WMI()
>     usb_devices = []
>     for usb_device in winmsgint.query("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType = 3"):
>         usb_devices.append({
>             "device_id": usb_device.DeviceID,
>             "volume_name": usb_device.VolumeName,
>             "drive_type": usb_device.DriveType,
>         })
>     return usb_devices
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     usb_devices = detect_usb()
>
>     for usb_device in usb_devices:
>         print(f"USB device detected: {usb_device['device_id']} ({usb_device['volume_name']})")
> ```